# Return partialview in layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

**View:**

```cs
@{Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account");}
```

**Controller**

```cs
//
// GET: /Account/Login
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return PartialView("_LoginPartial");
}

//
// POST: /Account/Login
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]    
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         return PartialView("_LoginPartial", model);
    }
    // enter code here
}
```

I'm just a newbie, so, If you don't mind could you help me?

**My question:**

In case, `ModelState` is invalid. How to return `PartialView("_LoginPartial", model)` and just update Validation error message in layout:
https://gyazo.com/ded5ec78e1b6a7bda96520fcca3879a3

Currently, I just returns only `PartialView` like this:
https://gyazo.com/b2fd098a5142837ee7ac8472670bcaa7

Comment: Why would you want to display a 'Login' and 'Register' form in the layout when 99.0% of the time it will not be needed by your users (you just degrading performance by generating unnecessary extra html. Follow the normal pattern, using the [Authorization]` attribute that automatically redirects to a 'Login' page (and on that page, include a 'Register' link that redirects to a 'Register' page)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for your reply. 
Cause I have to implement based on design.
We do not talk about login and register on the same page.
If I have multi model on same page, how can i return validation into partial view in order to show it on same page with other function.
Thanks for helping

Comment: Your first image shows `Login' and 'Register' on same page :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke This is design that I bought from Themeforest :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to resolved my question:

The reason you're getting a white page instead of your details View is because I am not submitting the form unobtrusively. You need to use an ajax-post form, otherwise, if you have an error, your action is going to return your PartialView, but it will return it back to the browser as a new page.

In your AjaxOptions, specify your form's div-container ID for UpdateTargetId parameter.

**View**

```
<div id="login-target">
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Login", "Account");}
</div>
```

**In Partial View**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new AjaxOptions {
                    HttpMethod = "POST",
                    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                    UpdateTargetId = "login-target" }))
{
  // add your form elements here
}
```

Reference: http://forums.asp.net/t/1923712.aspx?Validation+in+Partial+View+after+form+postback